# Cannot read property 'name' of null error in PHP/Vue JS form

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm redesigning an existing application form in Vue JS that interacts and posts via PHP. The form contains a large number of fields, most contain a HTML ID of something. I have a range of Vue JS methods, one of which parses the Vue JS form data and then submits this via a HTTP POST request. I'm getting an error with part of the code which seems to be thinking that my `element.name` is `null`.

I didn't write the code, and am simply debugging and attempting to fix this.

I've tried console logging my data, and I appear to indeed be getting a `null` value, I'm trying to figure out whether I may need to declare `var` or `let` infront of my `element` variable which is getting some property back.

The method in question causing the error which is called when submitting the form, is listed below:

```
/**
         * Parse Form Data
         * @return {object}
         */
        parseFormData: function parseFormData() {

          console.log('Data ->' + data)

          expanded = ''
          data = this.formData
          ignore = [
            'AddressSelection', 'NextPaydateDay', 'NextPaydateMonth',
            'NextPaydateYear', 'AskDebtsQuestion', 'loanreason',
            'loanreason-select', 'PersonalDebtQuestion'
          ]
          for (property in data) {
            if (ignore.includes(property)) continue // skips
            element = document.getElementById(property)
            console.log('Element ->' + element)
            switch (property) {
              case 'AppLoanPurposeOther':
                expanded += 'data[ApplicationPayday][AppLoanPurposeOther]=' + this.formData.AppLoanPurposeOther
                break;
              case 'EmpEmployerName':
                expanded += 'data[ApplicationPayday][EmpEmployerName]=' + this.formData.EmpEmployerName
                break;
              case 'EmpEmployedYears':
                expanded += 'data[ApplicationPayday][EmpEmployedYears]=' + this.formData.EmpEmployedYears
                break;
              case 'EmpEmployedMonths':
                expanded += 'data[ApplicationPayday][EmpEmployedMonths]=0'
                break;
              case 'EmpIndustry':
                expanded += 'data[ApplicationPayday][EmpIndustry]=' + this.formData.EmpIndustry
                break;
              case 'CheckDebtAdviceTeam':
                expanded += 'data[ApplicationPayday][CheckDebtAdviceTeam]=' + this.formData.CheckDebtAdviceTeam
                break;
              case 'AppWorkPhone':
                expanded += 'data[ApplicationPayday][AppWorkPhone]=' + this.formData.AppMobilePhone
                break;
              case 'AppHomePhone':data[ApplicationPayday][CheckDebtAdviceTeam]
                expanded += 'data[ApplicationPayday][AppHomePhone]=' + this.formData.AppMobilePhone
                break;
              case 'CheckDebtAdviceTeam':
                expanded += 'data[ApplicationPayday][CheckDebtAdviceTeam]=' + this.formData.CheckDebtAdviceTeam
                break;
              case 'CheckPhoneContract':
                expanded += 'data[ApplicationPayday][CheckPhoneContract]=' + this.formData.CheckPhoneContract
                break;
              case 'BankSortcode':
                expanded += 'data[ApplicationPayday][BankSortcode]=' + this.formData.BankSortcode.replace(/-/g , '')
                break;
              default:
                if (element.name === '') continue
                console.log('Element Name ->' + element.name)
                var string =
                expanded += element.name + '=' + data[property]
            }
            expanded += '&'
          }
          expanded = encodeURIComponent(expanded.substring(0, expanded.length - 1))
          expanded = expanded.replace(/%3D/g , '=')
          expanded = expanded.replace(/%26/g , '&')
          expanded = expanded.replace(/%20/g , '+')

          return expanded
        }
```

The expected result shouldn't be giving me a `null` value, the error appears on:

`if (element.name == '') continue`

The error in the console shows:

[image]

`tlp_aff_id` is passed in the URL via: `?aff_id=something` and this does work, it's listed in my data as:

`tlp_aff_id: '<?php echo urldecode($params['aff_id']) ?>'`

Comment: `element.name === ''` checks explicitly for an empty string, and doesn't allow for any similar values. Try a double equal instead of triple, or add `element == null` to your if check

Comment: Adding: `if (element.name === '' && typeof element == null) continue` simply returns the same error, and changing `===` to `==` also returns the same error :/

Comment: For some reason `document.getElementById(property)` is `null` and so does `element` because of it. You can add this line  `if(!element) continue` before the `switch`statement

Comment: @RyanHolton Check the `typeof` _first_

Comment: Sorry, I removed the typeof from my comment. Realized that's only for `undefined`. And after testing, `element.name == ''` would not match to null. Try `element == null || element.name == ''`. Check for null first so that `element.name` won't throw an error.

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks!